# How to call extrinsic functions externally from rust?

Tags: extrinsic, rust

I need to call extrinsic functions, for example `utility -> batch(calls)` or `utility -> batchAll(calls)`. Which library do I need to use for this?

I can't find those examples in the web.

Comment: Are you asking to call these from JavaScript? or in what context?

Comment: I'm using Rust, but example can be in any language

Answer (score 11):

If your making a rust program then using subtx crate might be your best bet:

https://github.com/paritytech/subxt

For example here is how to call the api:

```
    let api = ClientBuilder::new()
        .build()
        .await?
        .to_runtime_api::<polkadot::RuntimeApi<DefaultConfig, DefaultExtra<DefaultConfig>>>();

    let mut iter = api.storage().system().account_iter(None).await?;

    while let Some((key, account)) = iter.next().await? {
        println!("{}: {}", hex::encode(key), account.data.free);
    }
```

https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/master/examples/examples/fetch_all_accounts.rs

Answer (score 10):

The easiest way to do this is with JavaScript and using the [Polkadot JS APIs](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/).

An example for batching transactions can be found [here](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/cookbook/tx#how-can-i-batch-transactions):

```
// construct a list of transactions we want to batch
const txs = [
  api.tx.balances.transfer(addrBob, 12345),
  api.tx.balances.transfer(addrEve, 12345),
  api.tx.staking.unbond(12345)
];

// construct the batch and send the transactions
api.tx.utility
  .batch(txs)
  .signAndSend(sender, ({ status }) => {
    if (status.isInBlock) {
      console.log(`included in ${status.asInBlock}`);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 4):

Besides the `Polkadot JS APIs`, I would also recommend to use [py-substrate-interface](https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface).

```
pip install substrate-interface
```

```
from substrateinterface import SubstrateInterface, Keypair


substrate = SubstrateInterface(url='ws://127.0.0.1:9944')
# or
# substrate = SubstrateInterface(url='wss://rpc.polkadot.io')
# substrate = SubstrateInterface(url='wss://kusama-rpc.polkadot.io')

alice = Keypair.create_from_uri('//Alice')
bob = Keypair.create_from_uri('//Bob')

# Transfer funds to Bob
call = substrate.compose_call(
    call_module='Balances',
    call_function='transfer',
    call_params={
        'dest': bob.ss58_address,
        'value': 1 * 10**12
    }
)

# Sign with Alice
extrinsic = substrate.create_signed_extrinsic(call=call, keypair=alice)

# Submit the txn
receipt = substrate.submit_extrinsic(extrinsic, wait_for_inclusion=True)

print(f'Extrinsic: {extrinsic}')
print(f'Status   : {receipt.is_success}')
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a bunch of different Substrate client libraries in the [Substrate documentation](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/integration/client-libraries/)

Besides those referenced in the above link, there is also the [Polkadot Java Client](https://github.com/emeraldpay/polkaj).

There are other ways to interact with a Substrate blockchain, depending on your needs, such as the [Substrate Sidecar API](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-api-sidecar).

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it in an external Rust project.

In this example, I have a pallet called `Auditor` in my node, and a dispatchable function called `claim_log` that can accept extrinsics.

I generate a signer first so that my extrinsic can be signed:

```rust
use substrate_api_client::{Api, compose_extrinsic, UncheckedExtrinsicV4, XtStatus};
use substrate_api_client::rpc::WsRpcClient;
.....
// Get the private key of the sender here
  let from = AccountKeyring::Charlie.pair();
  let api = Api::new(client).map(|api| api.set_signer(from)).unwrap();
```

Compose the extrinsic and sign it

```rust
let xt: UncheckedExtrinsicV4<_> = compose_extrinsic!(
      api.clone(),
      "Auditor",
      "claim_log",
      log_to_be_claimed.filename.to_string().into_bytes()
      // TODO: maybe get the date here
    );
```

I then submit the extrinsic to the node using this

```
let blockh = api.send_extrinsic(xt.hex_encode(), XtStatus::InBlock).unwrap();
```

I am utilizing this substrate project to perform my dispatchable functions that accept extrinsics: https://github.com/scs/substrate-api-client

Answer (score 0):

There is also an option to call extrinsics natively without using libraries.
[Here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/1263/1760) is a working example.